# Javascript Array [Possibly Length?] Issue

Tags: javascript

Folks,

I have this array:

```
var list = new Array('Archer','Archer','Banker','Lantern','Toryboy','The Barb','Tim 
Whiffler','Glencoe','Warrior','Nimblefoot','The Pearl','The Quack','Don 
Juan','Haricot','Wollomai','Briseis','Chester','Calamia','Darriwell','Grand 
Flaneur','Zulu','The Assyrian','Martini-Henry','Malua','Sheet 
 Anchor','Arsenal','Dunlop','Mentor','Bravo','Carbine','Malvolio','Glenloth','Tarcoola','Pat
ron','Auraria','Newhaven','Gaulus','The Grafter','Merriwee','Clean 
Sweep','Revenue','The Victory','Lord Cardigan','Acrasia','Blue 
Spec','Poseidon','Apologue','Lord Nolan','Prince Foote','Comedy King','The 
Parisian','Piastre','Posinatus','Kingsburgh','Patrobas','Sasanof','Westcourt','Night 
Watch','Artilleryman','Poitrel','Sister Olive','King 
Ingoda','Bitalli','Backwood','Windbag','Spearfelt','Trivalve','Statesman','Nightmarch','Pha
r Lap','White Nose','Peter Pan','Hall Mark','Peter Pan','Marabou','Wotan','The 
Trump','Catalogue','Rivette','Old Rowley','Skipton','Colonus','Dark 
Felt','Sirius','Rainbird','Russia','Hiraji','Rimfire','Foxzami','Comic 
Court','Delta','Dalray','Wodalla','Rising Fast','Toparoa','Evening Peal','Straight 
Draw','Baystone','Macdougal','Hi Jinx','Lord Fury','Even Stevens','Gatum Gatum','Polo 
Prince','Light Fingers','Galilee','Red Handed','Rain Lover','Rain Lover','Baghdad 
Note','Silver Knight','Piping Lane','Gala Supreme','Think Big','Think Big','Van der 
Hum','Gold and Black','Arwon','Hyperno','Beldale Ball','Just A Dash','Gurner's 
Lane','Kiwi','Black Knight','What A Nuisance','At Talaq','Kensei','Empire 
Rose','Tawrrific','Kingston Rule','Lets Elope','Subzero','Vintage 
Crop','Jeune','Doriemus','Saintly','Might and Power','Jezabeel','Rogan 
Josh','Brew','Ethereal','Media Puzzle','Makybe Diva','Makybe Diva','Makybe 
Diva','Delta Blues','Efficient','Viewed','Shocking','Americain');
```

It is throwing an error. I have tried it in multiple browsers. Firefox Web Developer error console for example says Missing `")"` after argument list.

Google Chrome says Uncaught Syntax Error - Unexpected identifier and interestingly has a formatting change after Russia (cold war conspiracy theory anyone?) in the list.

Comment: Ever heard of syntax highlighting? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the entry

```
'Gurner's Lane'
```

to

```
'Gurner\'s Lane'
```

or

```
"Gurner's Lane"
```

An IDE with syntax colouring would make the broken quotation obvious (in fact just like SO highlighting).

Answer (score 0):

You should declare like following to avoid the appostrophy error like
    `"x's"`.

```
var arlene2 = new Array("First element", "Second", "Last");
```

refer to [Declare an array in Javascript](http://freewebdesigntutorials.com/javaScriptTutorials/jsArrayObject/declareAnArray.htm)

Comment: I built the list in PHP MYSQL but thanks you are right I am going to need a strategy to deal with this situation.